# Android debug.keystore still not generate

Tags: android

i had problem with my debug.keystore file. when i tried to run my application in eclipse there is an error **Debug Certificate expired on...Unknown Android Packaging Problem**. i've already done tutorials and some steps to solve this but still failed, i have no a new debug.keystore file after do "clean" and restart the eclipse. can somebody tell me why and how to solve this with the best way?thanks for advance.

Comment: did you try with deleting the `.android` folder?

Comment: i just delete debug.keystore file. if i delete ".android" folder, is it will work fine or not?

Comment: Deletion of `debug.keystore` does not work? Then try with deleting `.android` folder, It (.android) will be regenerated when you run your app again.

Comment: @M Mohsin Naeem thank you very much. it works for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

The debug keystore is no way special. If it doesn't get generated automatically, generate one yourself and just copy it there. As long as you use the alias and password Eclipse, etc. expect, it should work. Details here: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#debugmode

Answer (score 0):

try with deleting the `.android` folder.

It (.android) will be regenerated when you run your app again.